# how can I exclude inner tag in p tag

Tags: beautifulsoup

I need to implement web scraping. working first time in beautifulsoup.
request for a url, got the results which have another url, date and the heading.
now I need to get results from the url fetched in the first result.

select the url and request for the same.
I need to select all the p tags, so added like find_all('p')

```
def get_inner_urlData(self,link_url):
    link_page=urllib.request.urlopen(link_url)
    link_soup=BeautifulSoup(link_page, 'html.parser')
    link_content=[]
    for p_tag in link_soup.find_all('p'):
     #p_tag.find('script').decompose()
      print(p_tag.replace_with())`
```

when printing the output it shows:

```
<p><script> bla bla </script></p>
<p> this is a correct para</p>
<p> this is a correct para </p>
```

how can I avoid the p tag with a script tag, I used decompose of script tag show some error like:

```
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not directly clear where does it fail in your code, but the usual way to remove script elements from an another element is to find all `script` elements and `decompose`:

```
for p_tag in link_soup.find_all('p'):
    # remove script elements
    for script in p_tag.find_all('script'):
        script.decompose()

    print(p_tag)  # or print(p_tag.get_text())
```

Comment: thank you alecxe, it works fine,
I'm new in beautiful soup please support me for RSS feed url.
Is there a lot of work to scrap RSS feeds url

Comment: in the output of the above script, there are blank p tags so how to avoid the same